# Castle Windsor upgrade from 2.5 to 3.3 (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I am upgrading NHibernate, Castle.Core, Castle.Windsor (from 2.5 to 3.3)

IIS Version: 7.5

I have this in my web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
          <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor"/> 
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I run my web application I straight away get runtime error page without any exceptions..and after checking the event logs I found this,

> *Exception information: 
>       Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
>       Exception message: Could not load type 'Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule' from
>   assembly 'Castle.Windsor'.    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node,
>   Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean
>   checkAptcaBit)    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String
>   typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement)
>
>   at System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name,
>   String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement
>   configElement)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1
>   moduleList)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext)
>
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context)    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) Could not load type
>   'Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule' from
>   assembly 'Castle.Windsor'.    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName)    at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase)    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node,
>   Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)*

Not able to find any solution for this....

Comment: What version of IIS are you running on and is the `<modules>` section inside of `configuration/system.webServer`?

Comment: If you are using the .NET 4.0 rather than 4.5 DLLs make sure you've got the full framework DLL rather than the client profile one, as the `PerWebRequestLifestyleModule` class is compiled out of the client profile one.

Comment: @JonathonRossi: Yes I am using .NET4.0 and it is full framework build and not a client profile one.

Comment: @JigarSheth You won't need to register it in `<httpModules>` in IIS 7.5, only in `<modules>`.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, there is no need to declare `<httpModules>` in IIS 7.5, and defining the `<modules>` tag within the `<system.webServer>` is enough.
Secondly, "Could not load type ..." is related to incorrect type, dll or even namespace. I think the required "PerWebRequestLifestyleModule" class has been moved to a new assembly, so you just need to update your nuget packages in order to add Castle.Facilities.AspNet.SystemWeb and replace the code below.

```xml
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.Facilities.AspNet.SystemWeb.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Facilities.AspNet.SystemWeb" />
</modules>
```